# AWS Lambda asynchronous invocation and batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I was just going through AWS java script library to see CloudWatchLogsDecodedData which encapsulates CloudWatchLogsLogEvent[]. Cloud watch invokes Lambda asynchronously. So whether lambda batches events into CloudWatchLogsLogEvent array or how that happens? Is it possible to report batchItemFailure here as we do during SQS Lambda polling? - to retry subset of events alone from the CloudWatchLogsLogEvent[]